# Which process to kill to stop a Kafka Connect Worker?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I want to kill my Kafka Connect distributed worker, but I am unable (or I do not know how) to determine which process running in linux is that worker.

When running

```
ps aux | grep worker
```

I do see a lot of worker processes but am unsure which is the connect worker and which are standard non-connect workers

It is true that only one of these processes was started yesterday and I suspect that that is the one, but that would obviously not be a sufficient condition in all cases, say for example if the Kafka cluster was brought online yesterday. So, in general, how can I determine which process is a Kafka connect worker?

What is the fool proof method here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the other worker processes are not related to connect, you can search connect process with properties file which you passed to start connect worker.

```
ps aux | grep connect-distributed.properties
```

There is no kill script for connect workers. You have to run `kill` command with SIGTERM to stop worker process gracefully.

Comment: Thanks, I found it. (And I know how to kill it ;) )

Comment: @SiLaf hi , How did you do that?